# Pointer not incrementing in printf statement?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

How come this piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int y=42;
  int *p=&y;
  (*p)++;
  printf("%d\n",*p);
  return 0;
}
```

outputs 43, as expected, but this piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int y=42;
  int *p=&y;
  printf("%d\n",(*p)++);
  return 0;
}
```

outputs 42?

Comment: Do you know why it is called **post**-increment?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Because the ++ is after the expression to which the operator is applied?

Comment: Did you try `printf("%d\n", ++*p);`?

Comment: @CostantinoGrana I'd say the visual representation is hinting on the way it is operating, and is most definitely secondary (not sure if it was a sarcastic comment though).

Comment: @EugeneSh. I should have used a . I was obviously joking.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Even if sometimes it's dangerous to assume that post increment increments after its use and leads to assuming that UB expressions should behave in a specific way.

Answer (score 2):

`x++` is the post-increment operator. It increments the variable it's called on, but evaluates to the value **before** the increment.

Breaking the `printf` statement up to two statements may make it clearer:

```c
int pBeforeIncrement = (*p)++; // After this statement, pBeforeIncrement + 1 == p
printf("%d\n", pBeforeIncrement);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  printf("%d\n",(*p)++);
```

It increments the value ***after*** passing the value to the print. It is called **post**increment.

```
  printf("%d\n",++(*p));
```

It increments the value ***before*** passing the value to the print. It is called **pre**increment.

```
int main(){
  int y=42;
  int *p=&y;
  printf("(*p) = %d\n",(*p));
  printf("(*p)++ = %d\n",(*p)++);
  printf("(*p) = %d\n",(*p));
  printf("++(*p) = %d\n",++(*p));
  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Ke5Y6e3q8